# Proving Lebesgue Measure for Infinite Sequence of Disjoint Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For homework, I need to show if {$A_i$} is an infinite sequence of disjoint sets all of measure 0, the countability axiom holds in that $\lambda$ ($\cup_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ $A_i$) = $\lambda$ ($\Sigma_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ $A_i$) = 0. I'm not having any trouble proving that the right side of the equation is 0, but the left side is giving me some trouble. I was originally thinking of applying the outer measure equation $\lambda^*$($\cup$ $A_i$) $\leq$ ($\Sigma$ $\lambda^*$ $A_i$), but I'm unsure if that case applies here, both from the fact that the equation is used for outer measure and for a countable collections.

Comment: You can apply the sub-additivity of the outer measure, which holds for arbitrary sets. When $A$ is $\lambda$-measurable, then $\lambda^*(A)=\lambda(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $r >0$ let $B_{i,r}$ be an open set with $A_i\subset B_{i,r}$ and $\lambda (B_{i,r})<r2^{-i}.$  Then  $$\lambda^*(\cup_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i)\leq \lambda^*(\cup_{i\in \Bbb N}B_{i,r})\leq \sum_{i\in \Bbb N}\lambda^*(B_{i,r})=\sum_{i\in \Bbb N}\lambda (B_{i,r})<\sum_{i\in \Bbb N}r2^{-i}=r.$$   This holds for all $r>0,$ so  $\lambda^*(\cup_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i)=0.$

Comment: Note that the result holds without the condition that the $A_i$ are pair-wise disjoint.